# Reset Identity of remote table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to truncate a remote table(connected by a linked server).

I can't use `TRUNCATE` on a remote table so I use `DELETE FROM table_name`. But the `IDENTITY` column doesn't reset.

Is there a way to reset it?

`DBCC CHECKIDENT` doesn't work on remote table.

Comment: Did you try adding the truncate statement in a stored procedure on the remote server and calling the stored procedure  from the linked server

Comment: @sahalMoidu The method works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
EXEC Server_Name.DBName.sys.sp_executesql N'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table_name'
```